# background image on coordinator layout with nested scroll view

Tags: android, xml

I have the xml shown below that is supposed to display a background image on the nested scroll view. however it only displays for android 5.0 going up but not for versions below lollipop. for the versions below 5.0 it only shows the circular image buttons without the background. any suggestions or ideas are highly appreciated and welcome

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="#000000"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ndwlogo"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <!-- Scrollable content goes inside-->
        <!--this is the parent linear layout-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="9">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/agenda_btn"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/agenda"/>
                <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/info_btn"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/info" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
                    android:id="@+id/maps_btn"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/maps"/>
                <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/news_btn"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/news" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/guide_btn"
                    android:src="@drawable/ndw_guide"/>
                <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/directory_btn"
                    android:src="@drawable/directory" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/social_btn"
                    android:src="@drawable/socialmedia"/>
                <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/partners_btn"
                    android:src="@drawable/partners" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/showtimer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/showtimer" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                    android:id="@+id/timerday"
                    android:text="@string/countdowndefault"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/countdowndefault"
                    android:id="@+id/timerhour" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/countdowndefault"
                    android:id="@+id/timermins"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/countdowndefault"
                    android:id="@+id/timersec" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```